# lin((1, 1, −1, −1),(1, 2, 0, 1),(1, 1, 3, 1),(1, a, 2, −1))

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there a value of parameter "a" such that for it space
lin((1, 1, −1, −1),(1, 2, 0, 1),(1, 1, 3, 1),(1, a, 2, −1))
Is the solution of one (non-zero) equation with four unknowns?

Comment: What does the notation "lin" mean?

Comment: John Lin is a space spread on a given set (in this case these vectors)

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?